# Database Table design

Tags: database, database-design

I am having a problem choosing the variable types for database table. 
Can someone please give me some general guidelines as to how to choose the types? The following are some of the questions I have --

1. What should an userid be? An INT seems small as the design should take large number of users into account. So if not INT what else? BIGINT? VARCHAR? Am I not thinking straight?
2. When should I choose varchar and text and tinytext, binary?

I searched online and did not find any helpful links. Can someone point me in the right direction? Maybe I need to read book.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update for 2013**: The internet now has roughly the same number of users as a signed 32-bit integer. Facebook has about a billion users. So if you're planning on being the next Google or Facebook, and you *definitely* won't have time to re-engineer between now and then, go with something bigger. Otherwise stick with what's easy.

*As of 2010:*

An int seems small? Are you anticipating having 2,147,483,648 users? (For the record, that's like 1 in 3 people in the world, or 400 million more than the total number of people who use the internet; or 5 and a half times more users than Facebook).

Answer: use an int. Don't overthink it. If you get in a situation where our old friend the 32-bit integer just isn't cutting it for you, you will probably also have a staff of genius college graduates and $5b capital infusion to help solve the problem then.

Comment: Maybe the OP is running an 8-bit version of SQL

Comment: Yes. you are correct. I am over thinking it. In fact I even had a feeling I am not thinking straight. Its mostly because I somehow was thinking the max is 65535 as if I am working on a 16 bit machine. Have no idea why. 

Can you also talk about the others? Those are bigger questions for me. Is there a general rule for these?

Comment: @user220201 Unless I'm missing something it just doesn't sound like you have an actual problem yet. When your data sets get so large, or your transaction volumes so high that you start having to worry about how to manage them, then you have specific problems to solve and you can come back here and get SQL experts to help with those specific problems. Until then just use varchar for text, bit for boolean, int for numbers, binary for blobs (images, documents, etc) etc. Worry about what's easy to build :)

Comment: Yes. That is correct again. I don't have a problem with those yet. I am in the design/implementation phase and not a database guy as you can tell. Just want to make sure I use the correct types early on in the process.

Answer (score 1):

I would actually make a user ID a character type since I'd rather log in as "pax" than 14860. However, if it has to be numeric (such as if you want the name to be changed easily or you want to minimise storage for foreign keys to the user table), an integer should be fine. Just how many users are you expecting to have? :-)

I would always use `varchar` for character data since I *know* that's supported on all SQL databases (or at least the ones that matter). I prefer to stay with the standards as much as possible so moving between databases is easier.

Comment: @Graphain, caught me mid-edit, but introducing a user ID is often an artificial key that's not necessary. It depends on your needs (for example, the stuff inside the parentheses in my edit).

Comment: Thanks for the varchar clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Your `username` field should probably be a `varchar` (you pick the length).  If you have an `id_user` on the `user` table, I agree with the above answers that `int` (2 billion) will more than adequately cover your needs.

As far as you alphanumeric data types, it depends on how long you want it to be.  For example, I think a `varchar(255)`, or probably even smaller (personally I'd go with 50), would work for a `username` and `password` field.  [This chart might help you](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_datatypes.asp).

`Binary` would be for storing non-character data such as images.  `bit` can be used for boolean values.

A couple other useful types are `uniqueidentifier` for UUID/GUID and `xml` for XML.  Although you can also use `varchar` or text types for those too.

There's also `nvarchar` for Unicode in SQL Server and several date types (I'm glad they came out with `date` in SQL Server 2008 which doesn't include a time such as `smalldatetime`).

Comment: Thanks. That is the exact thing I am looking for, just the standard way to do things.